# Google Script Services: Charts without UiApp

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script, dashboard

`UiApp` is deprecated, but the Charts service isn't.  They direct you to use the HTML service instead.

How would one replicate the functionality of this simple chart/dashboard from this Apps Script tutorial: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard

In the tutorial you build a dashboard (from the Charts service) and then use the now deprecated `UiApp` to create the HTML output as follows:

```
var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();

  dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
                .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                    .add(ageFilter).add(genderFilter)
                    .setSpacing(70))
                .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                    .add(pieChart).add(tableChart)
                    .setSpacing(10)));

  uiApp.add(dashboard);
  return uiApp;
```

I can't figure out how to make the dashboard without UiApp!